# Facebook Send button does not show up on Gwt popup panel?

Tags: facebook, gwt, button, send

I'm trying to get Facebook send or like button display on GWT popup panel and I am not successful. When inspecting the generated HTML, facebook HTML button looks properly inserted into  but it just does not show up. Save Facebook button works well in html page (not on GWT panel).

Have you ever had success in displaying Facebook Send or Like or Share button in GWT? I know I ca implement FB Like button myself using API or other libraries. But I do it need that. I need standard Facebook Send button to be used in my GWT application.

Please advise me if you have experience and were successful.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and it was because, in the html file's script tag, I had changed and not updated the src="path" to a valid path.  I had a wrong directory listed in the path.  For me, it's correct now with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="clienttest/clienttest.nocache.js"></script>
```

I rebuilt, and the image appeared on the page.  This problem was keeping the entry point module from loading.